# How Does The Base64 Work and How To Encode/Decode in it?

Tags: python, encoding, decoding

I have a problem that asks me to encode a string to base64 format! I think I got it based on my code! The string: "Man" works and other short strings work. But the string: "this is a string!!" doesn't work! And also I want to use the non-padding version. The questions asks me to use the non-padding version. Can you please explain the process of how to encode this string: "this is a string!!"! I have to turn the letters to ascii, and then turn them into binary and divide them into 6 bytes and then turn them to decimal and refer to a chart of ascii and then use them. This is all I know! But, please don't give me the code. I want to try out the coding on my own. But please explain the process. There are no good videos explaining this topic! And by the way, I am using python 
Thank you

Here is the code I have:

```py
def decimal(binary):
    binary = str(binary); power = len(binary)-1
    values = []

    for x in binary:
        if x == "1":
            values.append((x, 2**power))
        power -= 1
    
    return sum([v for b,v in values if b == "1"])


string = "Man"

byte = ""
for x in string:
    byte += bin(ord(x))[0] + bin(ord(x))[2:]


values = []
for x in range(0, len(byte), 6):
    values.append(byte[x:x+6])

abc = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"

table = {x:abc[x] for x in range(len(abc))}
print("".join(table[decimal(x)] for x in values))
```

I am using python!

Comment: Your question needs a lot more details. What language are you using? What did you try? In what way did it not work? This question is also definitely a duplicate of something - encoding and decoding is something that gets asked about a lot.

Comment: I am using python, and I tried several strings like "Man", "Hey" and more. For these strings, it works, but when I try "This is a string!!!", it doesn't work!

Comment: Clarifications should be added in the question, not in the comments. You also need to actually show us some code and its output for us to be able to give you any advice about it.

Comment: Ok! I will give the code!

Comment: Alright, I gave the code!

Answer (score 0):

Adjusted parts are explained using in-line comments:

```
import sys   # merely for manipulation with supplied arguments 
import math 

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    string = "This is a string!!!"
else:
    string = ' '.join([sys.argv[i] for i in range(1,len(sys.argv))])

def decimal(binary):
    binary = str(binary); power = len(binary)-1
    values = []
    for x in binary:
        if x == "1":
            values.append((x, 2**power))
        power -= 1
    return sum([v for b,v in values if b == "1"])

byte = ""
for x in string.encode('utf-8'):     # ASCII is a proper subset of UTF-8
    byte += bin(x)[2:].rjust(8,'0')  # get binary string of length 8

byte = byte.ljust(math.ceil(len(byte)/6)*6,'0') # length must be divisible by 6 

values = []
for x in range(0, len(byte), 6):
    values.append(byte[x:x+6])

abc = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
table = {x:abc[x] for x in range(len(abc))}

print(string)                                 # input
padding = '=' * (((3 - len(string.encode('utf-8'))) % 3) % 3)
ooutput = "".join(table[decimal(x)] for x in values)
print(ooutput)
print(ooutput + padding)                       # for the sake of completeness

import base64   # merely for comparison/reference output
                # ↓↓↓ output from base64 module ↓↓↓
print(base64.b64encode(string.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8'))
```

**Output**: `.\SO\66724448.py ěščř  ĚŠČŘ & .\SO\66724448.py`

```
ěščř ĚŠČŘ
xJvFocSNxZkgxJrFoMSMxZg
xJvFocSNxZkgxJrFoMSMxZg=
xJvFocSNxZkgxJrFoMSMxZg=
This is a string!!!
VGhpcyBpcyBhIHN0cmluZyEhIQ
VGhpcyBpcyBhIHN0cmluZyEhIQ==
VGhpcyBpcyBhIHN0cmluZyEhIQ==
```